Facebook insights API not returning all expected fields?
curl -G \
  -d "fields=campaign_name,adset_id,adset_name,impressions,clicks,cpc,spend,date_start,date_stop" \
  -d "time_range={'since':'2023-07-01','until':'2023-09-30'}" \
  -d "access_token=${FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/act_"$FACEBOOK_ACCOUNT_ID"/insights

Returns
{
  "data": [
    {
      "impressions": "*******",
      "clicks": "*****",
      "cpc": "*****",
      "spend": "**********",
      "date_start": "2023-09-25",
      "date_stop": "2023-09-30"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "****",
      "after": "****"
    }
  }
}

Why is it not returning the other fields like campaign_name, adset_id etc?? I'm getting the field names from here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/7ec7292c1ce3c78e2005d730da0092e28458af95/src/FacebookAds/Object/Fields/AdsInsightsFields.php#L46

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/#levels
I needed to set the level parameter: -d "level=adset" \
